# No route matches in Rails code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for, collection-select

This code is all based on the Ruby on Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl. I created an `assigned` action in my `users_controller` with

```
def assign
  puts "in assign..."
  @scout = User.find(params[:follower_id])
  @der   = User.find(params[:followed_id])
end
```

I realize this doesn't do anything currently, but in the `_follow` partial, I have

```
<%= form_for @user, url: { action: "assign" } do |f| %>
  <div><%= hidden_field_tag :follower_id, @user.id %></div>
  <%= f.label :followed_id, "Assign #{@user.name} to" %>
  <%= f.collection_select :following, @ders, :id, :name, prompt: true %>
  <%= f.submit "Assign", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

But I'm getting the error `No route matches {:action=>"assign", :controller=>"users", :id=>"4"}`. I'm new to rails so this could just be a stupid question. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to modify my `routes.rb` file? Also, if I tried `<%= form_for @user do |f| %>`, how does the controller know which action to use? Is it based on the action displaying the form?

Edit: my `routes.rb` file is

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root                'static_pages#home'
  get    'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
  get    'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
  get    'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get    'signup'  => 'users#new'
  get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  resources :relationships,       only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

Edit 2: the HTML generated by @Rich's `form_for` block is

```
<form class="edit_user" id="edit_user_5" action="/users/5/assign" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="...">
  <label for="user_followed_id">Assign Mr. Marley Muller to</label>
  <select name="user[following]" id="user_following">
    <option value="1">Example User</option>
    <option value="2">Matthew Swartz</option>
    <option value="3">Joseph Swartz</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Assign" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

Which makes sense why I'm currently getting a can't find id error since it's not sending a real id (`edit_user_5`)

Edit 3: Here are the parameters being passed for the request

```
Started PATCH "/users/6/assign" for 68.100.59.128 at 2015-12-15 03:54:39 +0000
Processing by UsersController#assign as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "user"=>{"following"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Assign", "id"=>"6"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
Unpermitted parameter: following
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with 'id'=):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:69:in `assign'
```

Edit 4: With the following routes file,

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root                'static_pages#home'
  get    'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
  get    'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
  get    'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get    'signup'  => 'users#new'
  get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
      match :assign, to: :assign, via: [:post, :patch]
    end
  end
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  resources :relationships,       only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

and the following form for assigning one user to follow another,

```
<%= form_for @user, url: { action: "assign" } do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :follower_id, "Assign #{@user.name} to" %>
  <%= f.collection_select :following, @ders, :id, :name, prompt: true %>
  <%= f.submit "Assign", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I am getting the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#assign` error of `Couldn't find User with 'id'=`, but with the following parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"...",
 "user"=>{"following"=>"3"},
 "commit"=>"Assign",
 "id"=>"4"}
```

The ID's are correct: `"user"=>{"following"=>"3"}` and `"id"=>"4"`, I believe I am just trying to access them incorrectly. This is the assigns action in the users controller:

```
def assign
  @scout = User.find(params[:id])
  @der = User.find(params_hash[:followed_id])
  # make scout follow der here
  redirect_to @scout
end
```

Thoughts?

Comment: show your `routes.rb` file please.

Comment: The way it works is, you need to define a route in your `routes.rb` file which is mapped to a controller's action. So, the error message you got because either you did not define the route, or you did it wrong.

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam, see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a combination of Emu and Rich's answers. The form in the HTML is

```
<%= form_for @user, url: { action: "assign" } do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :follower_id, "Assign #{@user.name} to" %>
  <%= f.collection_select :following, @ders, :id, :name, prompt: true %>
  <%= f.submit "Assign", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

With controller action

```
def assign
  @scout = User.find(params[:id])
  @der = User.find(params[:user][:following])
  @scout.follow(@der)
  redirect_to @scout
end
```

and routes as

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root                'static_pages#home'
  get    'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
  get    'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
  get    'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get    'signup'  => 'users#new'
  get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
      match :assign, to: :assign, via: [:post, :patch]
    end
  end
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  resources :relationships,       only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

Answer (score 7):

In your **routes.rb** file you have to define the route for the specific controller action like that:

```
resource :users do 
  member do
    post 'assign' # change the request method to 'put'
  end
end
```

It will then generate a route for your **assign** method in the controller like: `users/4/assign`

For more info visit [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: See the comment I posted under @Rich's answer

Comment: @mjswartz, you're submitting the form to an existing object. So, the `post` action would be `put`.

Answer (score 2):

To add to `Emu`'s answer, the code you have won't work...

```
def assign
  puts "in assign..."
  @scout = User.find(params[:follower_id])
  @der   = User.find(params[:followed_id])
end
```

The params you'd get from the `form_for` object would be structured as:

```
params[:user][:follower_id]
params[:user][:followed_id]
```

You'd have to use the following:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def assign
      @scout = User.find params[:id]
      @der = User.find params_hash[:followed_id]
   end

   private

   def params_hash
      params.require(:user).permit(:followed_id)
   end
end
```

You could also get rid of the `hidden` field in your form if you're using the same `@user` object to populate it:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: { action: "assign" } do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :followed_id, "Assign #{@user.name} to" %>
  <%= f.collection_select :following, @ders, :id, :name, prompt: true %>
  <%= f.submit "Assign", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

---

**Update**

You need to include `:assign` in your routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root                'static_pages#home'
  resources :static_pages, only: [], path: "" do
     collection do
        get :help, :about, :contact
     end
  end

  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy], path_names: {new: "login", create: "login", destroy: "logout"}

  resources :users, path_names: { new: "signup" } do
    member do
      get :following, :followers, :assign
    end
  end
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  resources :relationships,       only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

Comment: I applied yours and @Emu's changes, but I'm getting the following error: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/users/7/assign"):`

Comment: That's because `@emu` put your routes to `post` - you should make it `match :assign, to: :assign, via: [:post, :patch]` - this should resolve the issue

Comment: Rich, I added your code snippet from this comment, but I'm getting an error of `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#assign` with `Couldn't find User with 'id'=`. See my edit for the HTML generated by the `form_for` block.

Comment: Hmm this is interesting. Are you sure your posted HTML is still what shows? Also, what is being passed as your params for the request?

Comment: Rich, I will double check later tonight. I have coded a website and grails before and you can put println statements in the controller and have it output to console for debugging without tests. I haven't been to figure out how to do that in rails. Is there a way I can do `println "params: " + params`?

Comment: the HTML is correct. See my newest edit for the parameters being passed for the request.

Comment: your routes update breaks a lot of stuff in my website. Applying only the snippet `get :following, :followers, :assign` gets me back to an older error of a missing assign route.